# What is the difference between grep -e and grep -E option?

Tags: grep

I am trying to understand the difference between `grep -e` and `grep -E`. Now from `grep manpage` I got:

> -E, --extended-regexp
>
> Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression (see below).
>
> -e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN
>
> Use PATTERN as the pattern; useful to protect patterns beginning with -

The above explanation does not make sense for me.

So, can someone explain it to me using `examples` what is the difference between the two  and when to use which option.

PS: Version: grep (GNU grep) 2.10

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17949/what-is-the-difference-between-grep-egrep-and-fgrep

Comment: The purpose of `-e` is really just to disambiguate when a regex starts with a dash.  So `grep ---foo` gives `unrecognized option: ---foo` but you can say `grep -e ---foo` to grep for the regular expression `---foo`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`-e` is strictly the flag for indicating the pattern you want to match against. `-E` controls whether you need to escape certain special characters.

`man grep` explains `-E` it a bit more:

```
Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions
In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (, and ) lose their 
special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions \?, \+, \{, \|, \(, and \).

Traditional  egrep  did  not  support  the  {  meta-character, and some egrep 
implementations support \{ instead, so portable scripts should avoid { in grep -E
patterns and should use [{] to match a literal {.

GNU grep -E attempts to support traditional usage by assuming that { is not 
special if it would be the start of an invalid interval specification. 
For example, the command grep -E '{1' searches for the two-character string {1 
instead of reporting a syntax error in the regular expression.  POSIX.2 allows 
this behavior as an extension, but portable scripts should avoid it.
```

Comment: so this is the reason when I do `echo "hello" | grep -o -e 'h|l'` I get no output because `|` lost its special meaning and when I do `echo "hello" | grep -o -E 'h|l'` I get the desired output.

Comment: Yes. `echo "hello" | grep -o -e 'h' -e 'l'` will work if you want to toss the `-E` away in this case.

Comment: `grep -e -o 'h|l'` will match literally `h|l` while `grep -e -o 'h\|l'` will match `h` or `l` and with -E it's the contrary

Comment: @ronnie it's unfortunate you need 200+ reputation to have that "feature" follow you between SE sites...

Answer (score 12):

Also `grep -e` allows to use several strings for searching: `'grep -e 'abc' -e 'def' -e '123'` will look for any of the three of these strings: `abc` as well as `def` and `123`.

This works quite similar to `grep 'abc\|def\|123'` where `\|` stands for `or` but could be a bit clearer to read.

As the most important facts on `grep -E` are already explained here, I just want to add what I summed up on this topic on a quite similar question: [Regular Expression for finding double characters in Bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70933/regular-expression-for-finding-double-characters-in-bash/71532#71532)

Answer (score 4):

Just to elaborate on the `-e` option. `-e` is often optional:

```
grep PATTERN
```

is identical to

```
grep -e PATTERN
```

unless, as stated in an earlier Answer and in the man pages, there are multiple search patterns, or to protect a pattern beginning with a hyphen (-).

Comment: Just to clarify, I believe -e is the same as -G, only that it can be used to pass multiple arguments. From the manual: "-G, --basic-regexp..    Interpret PATTERN as a basic regular expression (BRE, see below).  This is the default." So there are still only 3 types of pattern matching, basic (default), extended and pcre).

Answer (score 3):

> see below

/extended

> grep  understands  three  different  versions  of regular expression syntax: “basic,” “extended” and “perl.” In GNU grep, there
>   is no difference in available functionality between basic and extended
>          syntaxes.  In other implementations, basic regular expressions are less powerful.  The following description applies to extended
>   regular expressions; differences for basic  regular  expressions  are
>          summarized afterwards.  Perl regular expressions give additional functionality, and are documented in pcresyntax(3) and
>   pcrepattern(3), but may not be available on every system.

So, once again.

> In GNU grep, there is no difference in available functionality between basic and extended syntaxes

Comment: the *functionality* is the same between basic and extended but the syntax is slightly different.  regexp special chars like `(`, `)`, `|` etc need to be backslash-escaped to have their special meaning in basic regexp, but not in extended (where they need to be escaped to be treated as a string literal)