# Only allow hexadecimal regex

Tags: regular-expression

I want a regex using the grep command which only prints out the hexadecimal-notated strings.

This is my command:

```
grep "0x[A-Fa-f0-9]{1,6}" test.txt
```

test.txt:

```
0x2a
0xF
0x1111
0x0ZZZ
0x4dz5
```

Expected output:

```
0x2a
0xF
0x1111
```

Output:
Empty

How to do this? Thanks

Comment: Do you require the hex string to be by itself on a line? Or separated from surrounding characters by ... a space? Non-hex char?

Comment: @JeffSchaller All strings will be on a separate line anyway, so nothing special for that needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{n,m}` syntax is part of the Extended Regular Expression set, which means that you need to enable that in grep with the `-E` flag. To require that the full line matches the hex representation, add the `-x` flag (or use the `^` and `$` anchors):

```
grep -Ex '0x[A-Fa-f0-9]{1,6}'
```

or

```
grep -E '^0x[A-Fa-f0-9]{1,6}$'
```

I also changed the surrounding quotes from double- to single-, to prevent unintended expansion of the `$` character.

More regex reading on Stack Exchange:

- [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y/119906#119906)
- [What is the difference between grep -e and grep -E option?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50512/what-is-the-difference-between-grep-e-and-grep-e-option/50514#50514)