# what does the following egrep command do in combination with the "ip a" command?

Tags: grep, regular-expression, ip, ip-address

```
ip a | egrep '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}'
```

Can somebody explain what the above command will do?

Comment: egrep as a synonym for `grep -E`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17949/what-is-the-difference-between-grep-egrep-and-fgrep and the differences in basic & extended regular expressions (and more) : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It first runs the `ip` command with the `a` argument, which, on Linux, is short-hand for `ip address`, which will output several stanzas of several lines corresponding to your network devices and their possible network addresses.

That output is then sent to the `egrep` command, which is asked to match (print) lines of its input that match the given regular expression. The regular expression appears intended to match a superset of IPv4 addresses.

The regular expression specifically matches:

- (grouped together) - "any single digit between 0 and 9: between 1 and 3 of those, followed by a period" -- and require three items of that group, in sequence,
- followed by a single digit between 0 and 9: between 1 and 3 of them.

IP addresses would match this pattern; for example: `1.234.56.7` or `1.1.1.1`, but non-IPv4 addresses would also match (if they showed up in `ip a`'s output), such as: `999.888.777.666` or even `1.2.3.999`.