# Using egrep in /var/spool/postfix returns no results

Tags: shell, postfix, search

My machine is using CentOS 7.1. I'm trying to search through all the files within `/var/spool/postfix`.

The way I'm trying to achieve this is with:

```
$ egrep -lir --include="*.*" "somemail@somedomain.com" ./ > /root/results.txt
```

However, that search always comes back empty (`results.txt` is created, but there's nothing inside). Thinking that there might be a problem with `@`, or the `--include`, I've reduced the search to:

```
$ egrep -lir "somedomain.com" ./ > /root/results.txt
```

But that gives no results as well. I'm positive that there's at least ONE file with the string I'm looking for, so there should be at least one result within the *.txt.

**How can I find the files containing the desired string, by using `egrep`?** If that's not possible, any other searching method is welcome.

**Why I need this / Background**

Due to poor choice of email account and password, the machine was used to send around 500k spam messages, which started bouncing back pretty quickly, filling up the HDD. The offensive email account was deleted, the machine taken offline, and now I'm trying to hunt down a specific email message, among all those in `/var/spool/postfix/defer` and `/var/spool/postfix/deferred`.

I gues I could use a variant of `mailq > /root/results.txt`, but I'd like to do it with `egrep, grep, find` or any other command which returns already filtered results.

Comment: mailq|grep mail@domain maybe? or grep -r mail@domain * maybe?

Answer (score 1):

The GNU `grep` can do the regular expression searches using the `-E` switch, so there's no need to use `egrep`.

I'd do the following:

```
$ grep -rilE 'somemail@somedomain.com' . | tee /root/results.txt
```

You can change out the `| tee` with a `>` if you don't want to see the results via the terminal.

#### References

- [What is the difference between `grep`, `egrep`, and `fgrep`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17949/what-is-the-difference-between-grep-egrep-and-fgrep)

Comment: What's the practical difference between this suggestion and the OP's own `egrep -lir "somedomain.com" ./`?

Comment: @roaima - this uses `-E` and uses single ticks, the OP had double.